# Can I use objects which are listed horizontally in a single image file as background?

Tags: image, css, background, hover

I'm trying to use a single `.png` file with multiple objects listed inside, to change the background in `:hover`. The difference to other files, I'm use to working with is, that the objects in this file are listed next to each other and ***not*** under each other.
Is it possible to use a file like that or is it mandatory that the objects within the image file are under each other?

This is how I use an image files when the **objects** within are **under each other**:

```
.example.div {
  background : transparent url('img/info.png') bottom right no-repeat;
}

.example.div :hover {
  background : transparent url('img/info.png') top right no-repeat;
}
```

How does it work when there are e.g. **two** objects **next to each other** within the image file listed?

**Example file size : 123x25px**

Comment: Check out the [`background-position` style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position), or more specifically [CSS Sprites](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/)

Comment: If you have 123x25px images side by side in your sprite: For your first image you use background-position: 0 0; and for your second you use background-position: -123px 0; - like I mentioned in my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say that you have a sprite 200px X 100px containing two 100px X 100px images side by side.

Now you want to display each (100X100) image separately:

The first image will have `background-position: 0 0;`

The second image will have `background-position: -100px 0;` (**NB:** -100px for x value)

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/psuRa/1/)**

[image]

Comment: Hi Danield, thanks for your answer it worked, but to clarify it for others who might have the same question. For the example size of 123x25: `background-position: 0 0;` is ok, but when I tried `background-position: -123px 0;` the background image disappeared. I had to deduct the size of that image 24px from it an it's working  now with `background-position: -99px 0;`

Answer (score 3):

You can use coordinates.

background-position: 0px 0px;

So if your image is 200x100 (two 100x100 squres) then you would do...

```
.example.div {
  background : transparent url('img/info.png') no-repeat;
  background-position: 0px 0px;
}

.example.div :hover {
  background : transparent url('img/info.png') no-repeat;
  background-position: 100px 0px;
}
```

Comment: As you said, this is working if the image is 100x200 (2 times 100x100) but my question is about 200x100 (2 times 100x100) so this is not working for the exanple I gave.

Comment: Updated the answer... its the exact same method just with the numbers swapped.

Answer (score 1):

You can just change the positioning of the image to suit your image layout:

You are going from bottom to top, you just want to go from left to right.

```
.example.div {
  background : transparent url('img/info.png') top left no-repeat;
}

.example.div:hover {
  background : transparent url('img/info.png') top right no-repeat;
}
```

Or something like that

see demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/bdyNX/

Comment: I apologize, I copied from your code, which has a typo (a space between the div and hover selector) that I did not notice. I've included a demo to show this working.

Comment: +1 Thanks a lot for your efforts. I checked you demo and the image you used for it. Everything looks good and it's an answer to my question. The weird thing is that when I use the same code my background image is still jumping from the left to the right side of the div.